# hotkey for display settings on win 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hotkeys, display-settings

I have 3 screens with 2 computers which I use for personal stuff and work. I'm trying to avoid buying things like a KVM as my mouse and keyboard have already a built-in method for that.
I am looking for a solution to have the display settings on my personal computers to move between two configurations.
I am using Nvidia RTX 2070 video card.

[image: illustration]

To clarify - I change the source on my screen to see the other computer, but I want to move between configurations in order to not have a "missing screen" when I do it.

Comment: Windows does not support this natively, but some videocard drivers, such as AMD and nVidia potentially do support this in their drivers in one form or another. Intel integrated HD drivers have support for this in some of their drivers too. Can you edit your question and add which video card you have? brand and type?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I know AMD has this in their drivers as I own several AMD cards, but it has been a very long time that I had nVidia cards. It used to be possible, but I also read on the internet that it was removed at some point. For that reason, this is a comment, not an answer as I cannot test it. But you should be able to create more than one profiles, setup your desired monitor config per profile, and then find a way to switch quickly between profiles. Either from hotkey, or through the systray icon or desktop-right click menu.